# javascript library is toggled by gsp-template

Tags: javascript, grails, gsp

why is a declaration of 'g:javascript library="xyz"'-tag in a gsp or template switch off the declaration in a layout-gsp. And how can I force the behavior from  layout-gsp.

The problem I have is following:
I have to use the 'g:javascript library="xyz"'-tag in a template because I need the remoteLink tag in the template. If I render a gsp that includes these template I miss the javascript form the library xyz in the header (from the layout-gsp) of the html.

**Update**

Is there a way to configure the default JavascriptProvider-Class. This will solve my problem because I have not to use the g:javascript-tag in the gsp-template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by myself:
added configuration in Config.groovy

```
grails.views.javascript.library="xyz"
```

from there I never need the 'g:javascript library="xyz"'-tag in the template-gsp